# How to show custom view in UITableviewCell when button pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've recently started to learn iOS development and I ran into some problems.

I have a tableview with custom cell: Label, image view (hidden by default) and a button.
I want it to work so that when the button is clicked for the cell the image view gets shown.
The problem is that every time the cell is reused the image view is shown for the reused cell.
I want to get it to work so that if the button is pressed for the first cell, ONLY the first cells image view is shown. If the button for first and third cell is pressed the image view should show ONLY for first and third row and not any other row.

My current solution:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var cellTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var cellImageView: UIImageView!
    var showImageView = false


    @IBAction func showImageViewAction(sender: UIButton) {
        showImageView = true
        displayCell()
    }

    func displayCell() {
        if showImageView {
            cellImageView.hidden = false
        } else {
            cellImageView.hidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

And for the view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 30
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let customCell = cell as! CustomTableViewCell
    customCell.displayCell()
}
```

Any suggestions on how to create so that the image view gets hidden when the cell is reused?

Comment: So when you tap the button, the image view shows up on all 30 cells?

Comment: No. Currently if I tap the button for the first cell, the image view shows for the following cells: 1, 6, 11, 16, 21 and 26. I'ma assuming that it's because cell 6, 11, 16, 21 and 26 reuses the cell 1 when dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is called

Comment: I see. Are you able to get the specific cell [indexPath.row] first and then in-hide the image for that cell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check / uncheck the check box by tapping the cell in table view and how to know which cell has checked or unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513969/check-uncheck-the-check-box-by-tapping-the-cell-in-table-view-and-how-to-know)

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513969/check-uncheck-the-check-box-by-tapping-the-cell-in-table-view-and-how-to-know?noredirect=1#comment60634621_36513969.   You have to basically keep track of indexPath pressed into an array and in your cellForRow check if indexPath is present in array then show image else hide image. And while pressing button reload only that cell.

Comment: Thanks @ArunGupta for the suggestion. Now works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have to save the `cellImageview.hidden` status just do like so:

add protocol to inform the MainClass that the actionButton is pressed:

```
protocol customCellDelegate{
    func actionButtonDidPressed(tag: Int, value: Bool)
}
```

than in your CustomTableViewCell declare

```
var delegate: customCellDelegate?
```

and in the `@IBAction func showImageViewAction(sender: UIButton)` add:

```
@IBAction func showImageViewAction(sender: UIButton) {
   cellImageView.hidden = ! cellImageView.hidden
   delegate?.actionButtonDidPressed(self.tag, value: imageCell.hidden)
}
```

in your mainView make it conform to `customCellDelegate`

```
var status = [Bool]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let rowCount = 100
    for _ in 0 ..< rowCount{
        status.append(true)
    }
    return rowCount
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customcell
    cell. cellImageView.hidden = true
    cell. cellImageView.hidden = status[indexPath.row]
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}

func actionButtonDidPressed(tag: Int, value: Bool) {
    status[tag] = value
}
```

Comment: But in this case when I scroll till the end of table view and then scroll back the image view status isn't saved. So it becomes hidden again. I need to store somewhere the status of the image view for cell.

Comment: i've updated my post with a working (tested) code let me know if you need something else

Comment: Thanks. This works like a charm. Even better than my current solution using callbacks.