# How to save state of UIButton in a tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitableview

I currently have a tableViewCell with a button on it that when pressed a check mark appears.  I'm trying to save the state of the UIButton to NSUserDefaults.  There is also a separate viewController with a cell that has an X button that will delete the UIButton state saved in NSUserDefaults. I tried this 
but it didn't seem to work with a tableViewCell.  Here is my current code:

Custom Button:

```
class SaveButton: UIButton {

  // Images
  let buttonChecked = UIImage(named: "save_icon_greenCheck")
  let buttonUnChecked = UIImage(named: "save_icon_white")


  //Bool Property
  override var selected: Bool{
    didSet{
      if selected {
        self.setImage(buttonChecked, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
      }else{
        self.setImage(buttonUnChecked, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
      }
      NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(selected, forKey: "isBtnChecked")
     // NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame:frame)
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.setImage(buttonUnChecked, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
  }

  func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    self.selected = !self.selected
  }
}
```

TableViewCell:

```
class TvShowCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet var MainPosterImage: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet var MainTitleLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var imageWrapper: UIView!

  @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: SaveButton!

  override func awakeFromNib() {
  saveButton.selected = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isBtnChecked") // here we obtain the last state of the button
  }

  @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
      sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "save_icon_greenCheck"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
   }
  }
```

IBAction to remove the UIButtonState:

```
    @IBAction func removeSavedObject(sender: AnyObject) {
        let searchTermsData = myDefaults.objectForKey(SAVED_SHOWS_KEY) as? NSData
        let searchTermsArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(searchTermsData!) as? [TvShowInfo]
         favoriteShowsArray = searchTermsArray!
          let location: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.favoritesTableView)
          let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.favoritesTableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location)!
          showToRemove = favoriteShowsArray[indexPath.row]

 //save UIButtonState here
      let save = SaveButton()
      save.selected = false
      myDefaults.setObject(save, forKey: "isBtnChecked")

  let savedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(favoriteShowsArray)
          myDefaults.setObject(savedData, forKey: SAVED_SHOWS_KEY)
          myDefaults.synchronize()
          favoritesTableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show custom view in UITableviewCell when button pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531010/how-to-show-custom-view-in-uitableviewcell-when-button-pressed)

Comment: Where is the function `removeSavedObject ` used, in the UITableViewController?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just save the button state instead of trying to save the whole button? The latter isn't working because when you try to save a whole object to NSUSerDefaults you need to archive it. Instead, you could just save the selected state as a bool, which since it is a default type, doesn't need to be archived. 
So when the button is selected, just save the selected state as a bool instead of as an object.

```
 override var selected: Bool{
didSet{
  if selected {
    self.setImage(buttonChecked, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  }else{
    self.setImage(buttonUnChecked, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
  }
  NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(selected, forKey: "isBtnChecked")
}
}
```

And then in your `@IBAction` for removing the state of the button, instead of crating a button object, setting it as not selected, and then saving it, just do this:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.setBool(false, forKey: "isBtnChecked")
```

Since you created your cell in storyboard, you should be doing your initialization like so:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    saveButton.selected = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isBtnChecked")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Comment: I have a problem retrieving the NSUserDefaults.  I use the line : saveButton.selected = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isBtnChecked") but I keep getting an error:  "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Comment: What's the problem? With the changes I made to your code, that should work fine now

Comment: Its the retrieving of the NSUserdefaults where the issue lies

Comment: What about in your `TableViewCell` `saveButtonPressed` method, you change the method to `saveButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) { sender.selected = !sender.selected }` Since you already have your didSet property observer, you don't need to be changing the image yourself.

Comment: Also, since it's saying the `boolForKey` part isn't working, this is probably because before you were saving the object. You probably need to delete your app from the simulator to clear out your defaults because even though it may be a bool now, in the defaults it could have conflicting values.

Comment: I tried those suggestions, still getting the same error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Comment: Did you create your view (specifically your custom cell) in code or with a storyboard?

Comment: I created it through stroyboard.

Comment: I put the new initialization code in the tableViewCell and it still isn't working.  Now I get a  EXC_BAD_ACCESS error every time the: <saveButton.selected = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isBtnChecked")> line in the cellForRowAtIndexPath is reached

Answer (score 0):

I think what you do from `awakeFromNib()` try it in `cellforrowforinindexpath`.
hope this will work :)

Comment: I tried that, I get a  "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" once it hits that line of code