# how to get check box functionality in tableview footer view

Tags: swift

i have to use checkbox in tableview footer, on check i have to display textfield.

in my ViewController
@IBOutlet weak var resultTable: UITableView!

in FooterCell

```
import UIKit

class FooterCell: UITableViewCell 
{
    @IBOutlet weak var textFld: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var submitBtn: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() 
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) 
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

this is my code in class

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? 
{
    let footer = resultTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "footer") as? FooterCell
    footer!.textFld.isHidden = true
    footer!.submitBtn.isHidden = true
    footer!.checkBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkBoxSelection(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return footer?.contentView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat 
{
    return 55
}

@objc func checkBoxSelection(_ sender:UIButton)
{
    let footer = resultTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "footer") as? FooterCell

    if askBool
    {
        footer!.checkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"CheckBox"), for: .normal)
        footer!.textFld.isHidden = false
        footer!.submitBtn.isHidden = false

        askBool = false
    } else
    {
        footer!.checkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named:"UnCheckBox"), for: .normal)
        footer!.textFld.isHidden = true
        footer!.submitBtn.isHidden = true

        askBool = true
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: i want check box functionality in footerview

Comment: What is your question _exactly_? What exactly did you try and what exactly doesn't work? Because if you expect a step-by-step guide or someone to do your work for you, such questions are off-topic here.

Comment: i have to customise the footer view in tableview for checkbox functionality like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513969/check-uncheck-the-check-box-by-tapping-the-cell-in-table-view-and-how-to-know

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add functionality to your footerView you need to use protocol to detect user has checked or unchecked button.

1) First, create a protocol

```
  protocol FooterCheckable: class {
        func isChecked()
    }
```

2) Then inside your footer view class do following inside checkbox action.

```
class TableViewFooter: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        weak var delegate: FooterCheckable?
        @IBAction func approveOrRejectBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
            delegate?.isChecked()
        }
    }
```

3) Inside your view controller you need to register your tableViewFooter with following code

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: yourFooterViewString, bundle: nil),
                   forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: identifier)
```

4) Then, again inside your View Controller class you need to have following code to use header and give delegate to your view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        if let footer = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? TableViewFooter {
            footer.delegate = self
            return footer
        }
        return nil
    }
```

5) Lastly, you need to be sure you need to conform your protocol inside the view controller and do whatever you need when header button checked.

```
extension ViewController: FooterCheckable {
func isChecked() {
}
}
```

That is happy ending hope it will be useful for you.